# The number of elements in {1,2,...,a}.{1,2,...,b}, where $ab=n^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, analytic-number-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $A_{a,b}$=$\{pq:p\leq a,q\leq b\}$, where $ab=n^2$ and $n^2$ is fixed.

How large is $A_{a,b}$? Does $A_{a,b}$ attain its lower value when $a=b=n$?

The case when $a=b=n$ is settled by Ford, and a stronger conjecture by Erdos is asking if $|M(G)|\geq |M(K_{n,n})|$ in general for all bipartite $G$ such that $e(G)=n^2$. Yet is there any development about the above weaker problem?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. Are $a,b$ fixed, or can they vary here? Also is $n$ in the index of $A_n$ the same as the one appearing in $mn$?

Comment: @Wojowu Thx I've edited my notation

Comment: Is the $n$ in $mn$ the same one as the one in $ab=n^2$?

Comment: @Wojowu oh yea, an abuse of notation! not the same.

Comment: The case $a=b=n$ is the *Erdos multiplication table problem*, there are very good estimates for the size of $A_{n,n}$.

Comment: "Where $ab=n^2$ are two fixed integers" I don't really understand this. Is $n^2$ fixed, and we then choose two numbers $a, b$ whose product is $n^2$? Or do you mean: "where $a, b$ are two fixed integers, such that..."?

Comment: What is $M(G)$?

Comment: I think OP is asking if, given $n$, the lowest value in $\{|A_{a,b}\;|\; ab=n^2\}$ is attained at $|A_{n,n}|$. I checked that this is so if $1\le a\le b \le 1000$.

Comment: It seems $M(G)$ for a graph $G$ is a notion introduced recently by Narayanan, Sahasrabudhe  and Tomon in "The multiplication table problem for bipartite graphs" (Combinatorica vol. 37, pp. 991–1010 (2017)). It is the size of the set $\{ e(H): H \text{ is an induced subgraph of }H\}$ where $e(.)$ counts the number of edges.

Comment: ... OP asks both about the minimal value of $A_{a,b}$ where $a,b$ range over pairs $ab=n^2$ (which in theory might not require Ford's work), as well as about the order of magnitude of $A_{a,b}$; $A_{a,b}$ arises as $M(K_{a,b})$.

Comment: The closest two pairs whose product is a square can be is for $(n(n+1),n(n+1))$ and $(n^2,(n+1)^2)$. In this case Legendre's conjecture easily implies $A_{n^2,(n+1)^2}>A_{n(n+1),n(n+1)}$. Some more mileage can be got out of this approach and I wonder if maybe it can be used to fully answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Ford's methods provide lower bounds for this "asymmetric" multiplication table problem that match the lower bounds for the standard multiplication table problem.

Define $H(x,y,z) := \#\{n \le x : \exists d \in (y,z]  \text{ with } d \mid n\}$. Ford proved that $$H(x,y,cy) \asymp \frac{x}{(\log Y)^\delta (\log\log Y)^{2/3}}$$ whenever $c>1$ and $\frac{1}{c-1} \le y \le \frac{x}{c}$, where $Y := \min(y,x/y)+3$.

Now take $a \ge 1$ and consider $|[a]\cdot [n^2/a]|$, which is $|A_{a,n^2/a}|$ in your notation. If $a \le 4$ or $a \ge n^2/4$, then clearly $|[a]\cdot[n^2/a]| = \Omega(n^2)$, so we may assume otherwise. We claim $$\left|[a]\cdot[\frac{n^2}{a}]\right| \ge H(\frac{n^2}{4},\frac{a}{4},\frac{a}{2}).$$ Indeed, if $b \le n^2/4$ has some $d \in (a/4,a/2]$ with $d \mid b$, then $b/d \le (n^2/4)/(a/4) = n^2/a$, so $b = d\cdot \frac{b}{d} \in [a]\cdot[n^2/a]$. Therefore, using $x = n^2/4, y = a/4, c=2$, we obtain $$\left|[a]\cdot[\frac{n^2}{a}]\right| \gg \frac{n^2/4}{(\log Y)^\delta(\log\log Y)^{2/3}},$$ where $Y = \min(a/4,n^2/a)+3$. Since $Y \le n^2$, $\log Y \ge 2\log n$, so we obtain the desired result $$\left|[a]\cdot[\frac{n^2}{a}]\right| \ge c'\frac{n^2}{(\log n)^\delta (\log\log n)^{2/3}}$$ for some absolute $c' > 0$.

Comment: Using Theorem 1(v) of Ford's "The distribution of integers with a divisor
in a given interval" combined with the argument in Corollary 3 in said paper, it seems that the order of magnitude of $|[a] \cdot [n^2/a]|$ is $n^2 (\log m)^{-\delta} (\log \log m)^{-2/3}$ where $m = \min\{a,n^2/a\}$.